# Hide scrollbar for a particular div

Tags: css, reactjs

I have two div one is sidebar & another one is Categories bar, i want to hide scroll bar from categories bar but.

I tried

`#sidebar ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { visibility: hidden; }`

but it hide scrollbar from both div. Please help.

Comment: Please share your code of what you have tried

Comment: Please share more context, for eg, your code and the screenshot, and maybe which scroll bar you expect to be hidden

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use overflow?? like: `#sidebar { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: I tried this but it will stops my div to scroll

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to `categories bar` div. The class would target specific scrollbar you are trying to hide.

Something like this, use as reference and adapt to your own code.

```
<div id="sidebar">
  ...
</div>

<div class="categories-bar">
  ...
</div>

<style>
  #sidebar ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  
  .categories-bar ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>
```